# Web scraping com python em sites com autenticação

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Estou tentando automatizar um processo de obtenção de dados via web usando Python. No meu caso, preciso puxar as informações da página https://app.ixml.com.br/documentos/nfe. No entanto, antes de ir a essa página, precisa-se logar em https://app.ixml.com.br/login. O código abaixo teoricamente deveria logar no site:

```
import re
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser


username = 'meu email'
password = 'minha senha'

br = RoboBrowser()

br.open('https://app.ixml.com.br/login')

form = br.get_form()

form['email'] = username
form['senha'] = password

br.submit_form(form)

src = str(br.parsed())
```

No entanto, printando a variável src, eu obtenho o código fonte da página https://app.ixml.com.br/login, ou seja, antes de logar.  Caso eu insira as seguintes linhas no fim do código anterior

```
br.open('https://app.ixml.com.br/documentos/nfe')
src2 = str(br.parsed())
```

A variável src2 contém o código fonte da página https://app.ixml.com.br/.. Tentei algumas variações, como criar um novo objeto br, mas obtive o mesmo resultado. Como posso acessar as informações em  https://app.ixml.com.br/documentos/nfe?

Comment: Você está tentando se autenticar como um robô, e o site não dá permissão

Comment: Ah, entendi, obrigado. Existe alguma maneira de eu acessar então?

Answer (score 1):

A biblioteca *requests* também te permite realizar logins, ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

session = requests.Session()

# email e senha correspondem ao "name" das tags no html que se referem aos campos para login.

payload = {'email':'[SEU_EMAIL]', 
          'senha':'[SUA_SENHA]'
         }

# Fazer o login
s = session.post("https://docs.bsoft.com.br/", data=payload)

# Acessar a página pós login
s = session.get('https://app.ixml.com.br/documentos/nfe')

soup = BeautifulSoup(s.text, 'html.parser')
```

> Referência: [Scraping Data behind Site Logins with Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/scraping-data-behind-site-logins-with-python-ee0676f523ee)